# there is some mistake in the javascript and that is how to get output?

Tags: javascript, html

how to get output?
 there is some problem in the code that is i am not able to get out answer.
and i can't figure that is my mistake

```
<!Doctypehtml>
<html>
<title>new html</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script >
var number = document.getElementById("num1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("num2");
var out = document.getElementById("output");


number.addEventListener("input", sol);

number2.addEventListener("input", sol);


function sol(){

    var one = parseint(number.value);

    var two = parseint(number2.value);

    out.innerHTML = one+two;
    }

</script>

<input id="num1">+<input id="num2">

<p id="output"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The function is `parseInt` (with a capital `I`) not `parseint`.

Comment: Also prefer `textContent` over `innerHTML` when you're not rendering HTML.

Comment: If you use the developer tools on your browser you will be able to discover your error via the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what exactly you looking for:

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/tL185xfz/)</kbd>**

```js
var number = document.getElementById("num1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("num2");
var out = document.getElementById("output");

function sol(){

    var one = parseInt(number.value);
    var two = parseInt(number2.value);
    
    if(number2.value != '')
    {out.innerHTML = one+two;}
    else
    {out.innerHTML = '';}
    }
```

```html
<input id="num1">+<input id="num2" onkeyup="sol()">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change parseint to parseInt:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var number = document.getElementById("num1");
    var number2 = document.getElementById("num2");
    var out = document.getElementById("output");
    number.addEventListener("input", sol);
    number2.addEventListener("input", sol);
    function sol() {
        var one = parseInt(number.value);
        var two = parseInt(number2.value);
        out.innerHTML = one + two;
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/921/)**

Comment: While the parseint is using the wrong case, this will not completely fix OP's problem. Their function will never be called because the code before it is trying to access DOM elements before they are able to be accessed

Comment: @PatrickEvans Check the demo. I used this code inside the document.ready. I will update the same here too

Comment: Where has user tagged for **JQuery**?

Answer (score 2):

The function is `parseInt` (with a capital `I`) not `parseint` as mentioned Correctly by @Dai

```
   var one = parseInt(number.value);

    var two = parseInt(number2.value);
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/91d6aoo5/)

And also reason to use **textcontext** over the **innerHTML**

1. **innerHTML** parses content as HTML and takes longer.
2. **textContent** uses straight text, does not parse HTML, and is faster.

Using `isNaN()` function determines whether a value is an illegal number (Not-a-Number).

```
if (!isNaN(three))
 {
     //if its a valid number try to display the value to the output
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey first Of all try embedding the java script file into you code except writing an inline JS code because if the code is large then you may get stuck up in assigning events to ID by dertermining the ID values in the HTML.
Secondly, yes you have errors in the following code

```
function sol(){

    var one = parseint(number.value);

    var two = parseint(number2.value);

    out.innerHTML = one+two;
    }
```

/*the following lines need to be changed */
/* parseInt*/

```
        var one = parseInt(number.value);

        var two = parseInt(number2.value);
```

Thankyou !!